# Bootstrap collapsible panel, heading icon not updated when toggled programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap collapsible panels with icons in their headings which indicate an open/closed status.
This works fine (i.e.: the icon changes correctly) when clicking these icons directly.

However I now need to toggle these panels programatically (triggered by clicking hyperlinks), and while this correctly opens/closes the panel, it does not update the icon in the heading.

In the code below I created one panel which has a glyphicon that triggers its open/close action.
Below the panel is also a hyperlink with the `href` attribute referring to the ID of the panel. 
A small jQuery snippet takes care that when this hyperlink is clicked, the `collapse('toggle')` function of its target ID is called.
As you can see in the JSFiddle, the panel nicely collapses by clicking the 'Test' hyperlink, however the icon is not update.

As one can see, the difference between clicking the icon, or clicking the 'test' hyperlink, is that clicking the icon will toggle the `.collapsed` class of the `<span>` element containing the icon.
Clicking the hyperlink does NOT toggle this class.

By googling if found this bootstrap issue on github (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7213), which mentions an old issue which caused the same behaviour by clicking the heading itself (the icon in my case), while this obviously fixed, the problem still seems to exist in the `collapse()` function which can be used to toggle the panels programatically, this was also mentioned in the pull action done for this issue (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/7424#issuecomment-20107756), where @intellix indicates this isn't working correctly, but it doesn't seem to get picked up by somebody (or I might be interpreting it wrong, I'm not really familiar with github comments/issues/pulls...).

So is this still a bug in bootstrap? Or am I exepcting too much of it?

html:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="collapseicon clickable accordion-toggle  pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"></span>
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<a href="#collapseOne">Test</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').on('click', function()
          {
              var HashTag = $(this).attr('href');
             $(HashTag).collapse('toggle'); 
          });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6f6g536r/2/

Comment: Add the `collapsed` class to the icon when it's collapsed.

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks but that is a little too obvious :), the question was if bootstrap shouldn't take care of this automatically?

Comment: I added a comment to the first issue on Github, someone kindly responded and pointed me to the following issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13636 which exactly describes this behaviour. So yes, bootstrap should handle it, however sadly it's still open

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Bootstrap will handle this in the toggle function - instead you'd have to try something along these lines.

```
$('a').on('click', function()
{
    var HashTag = $(this).attr('href');
    $(HashTag).collapse('toggle'); 
    $('.collapseicon[href$="' + HashTag + '"]').toggleClass('collapsed'); 
});
```